# Can bootstrap modal dialog overlay another dialog?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

```
<button class="btn" onClick="$('#firstModal').modal('show');">First</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="firstModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <button class="btn" onClick="$('#secondModal').modal('show');">Second</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="secondModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        Some error message goes here.
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine; the only problem is that first dialog is displayed over the overlay of the second dialog. How can I fix this?

This is how it looks now:
[image]

And I want it to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that I can change z-index of the second "shadow" using this css rule:

```
.modal-backdrop.fade.in:nth-child(2){
    z-index: 1060 !important;
}
```

than I just need to set z-index of the second dialog to for example 1070 and that's it, although I am not sure about compatibility with older browsers.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a blog post about how to solve this stacking problem programatically: http://gurde.com/stacked-bootstrap-modals/

```
$(document)  
  .on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function(event) {
    $(this).appendTo($('body'));
  })
  .on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal.in', function(event) {
    setModalsAndBackdropsOrder();
  })
  .on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function(event) {
    setModalsAndBackdropsOrder();
  });

function setModalsAndBackdropsOrder() {  
  var modalZIndex = 1040;
  $('.modal.in').each(function(index) {
    var $modal = $(this);
    modalZIndex++;
    $modal.css('zIndex', modalZIndex);
    $modal.next('.modal-backdrop.in').addClass('hidden').css('zIndex', modalZIndex - 1);
});
  $('.modal.in:visible:last').focus().next('.modal-backdrop.in').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

Comment: I have not tested the answer below, but feel due to it not being backward browser compatible it doesn't match what I need right now. With that said, I have up-voted this answer as it has provided me a solution with a few adjustments... I found that there is an odd flicker when using this script, to get rid of this with latest bootstrap, simply comment out or remove line 18's ".addClass('hidden')" and comment out or remove line 20, all works sexy now. Thanks robert for this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the modal backdrop (overlay) is shared by all modals in the BODY.

But, you can use the 'show' event from the second modal to change the opacity on the first modal -- giving the effect of the overlay over the first modal:

```
$('#myModal2').on('show', function() {
    $('#myModal').css('opacity', .5);
});
```

Demo: **http://bootply.com/61322**

*EDIT*:

If you want to disable modal 1 while modal 2 is open, you can unbind modal 1 when modal 2 opens, and then restore modal 1 when modal 1 closes. **I updated the [Bootply](http://bootply.com/61322) for this**.

```
$('#myModal2').on('show', function() {
    $('#myModal').css('opacity', .5);
    $('#myModal').unbind();
});
$('#myModal2').on('hidden', function() {
    $('#myModal').css('opacity', 1);
    $('#myModal').removeData("modal").modal({});
});
```

Comment: This is not the best solution because user can still click on the button in the first dialog while the second is being displayed, but thanks for reply anyway

Comment: If I was able to set Z-index of backdrop (overlay) for every single dialog, problem would be solved

Comment: I think that would be very difficult. You'd have to create your own custom overlay/backdrop and disable the Bootstrap modal backdrop.

Comment: This is the simplest solution and there is no way to change the backdrop for each modal. "Amateur" is putting jQuery code inline in the onClick event as you've done.

Comment: I wanted to put here code as simplest as possible, I know it's amateur, therefore I am here and asking for advice

Comment: I didn't say only your solution is amateur, I said it is STILL amateur, There was no offence, I just still believe that there must be better solution, but as I said, I thank you for your effort

Answer (score 1):

You could add an attribute to "secondModal"

```
style="z-index:100000;"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this affects only the window but not that shadow in background

Comment: With javascript you could get the common parent (that wraps the entire dialog) and add the attribute via script just after showing the dialog.

Comment: @dadlyDev could you add some code please? Because I don't really understand how you meant it. Thanks

Comment: I realise you mean the dark background (Not the edge shadow)... You could use jquery and do something like $("modal-backdrop").css("z-index","99999") after showing. It would probably be a good idea to set it back to its original value after hiding the modal.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone stumbles across this.

1. Add this value to your main script tag on the your page

   ```
     var current_zindex = 1049;

     var current_zindex_bg = 1048;
   ```
2. in your document ready function add

   ```
     $('.modal').on('show', function () {
        current_zindex++;//increment z-index for your modals
        current_zindex_bg++;//increment z-index for your modal-backdrops
        $(this).css('z-index',current_zindex); //setting the modal backdrop
    });
   ```
3. Now in the **minifield** bootstrap file itself find this bit of code:

   ```
     '<div class="modal-backdrop '+r+'" />' //just search for "modal-backdrop" without the quotes

     change to:

     '<div class="modal-backdrop '+r+'"  style="z-index:'+current_zindex_bg+';" />'
   ```

That's it. You can find the same bit of code in the unminified boostrap.js by searching for "modal-backdrop" and follow the same process.

Clicking the top most backdrop will hide the top most modal as you would want.

Comment: .on("show.bs.modal", ... This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.

Answer (score 0):

To make overlays open other overlays, I added a simple line of JS in the event listener.

Thus any link inside an overlay will first close the overlay it is in.

Search for in the Bootstrap overlay code:

```
$(document).on('click.bs.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
```

Add to that function:

```
$this.closest(".modal").modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have modal `var modal = $('.some-selector').modal('show');`
first you want to change it's zIndex like: `modal.css({zIndex: 7760})`

you can find reference to its $backdrop in `modal.data()`, so you can access it and change anything: `modal.data()['bs.modal'].$backdrop.css({zIndex: 7750});`

Comment: I tried this and got the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$backdrop' of undefined`. I am using bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this way: (note : You need bootstrap 3 for this)

```
<button class="btn" data-target="#firstModal" data-toggle="modal">First</button>
```

```
<div id="firstModal" data-target="#secondModal" data-dismiss="modal" 
data-toggle="modal">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <button class="btn" onClick="$('#secondModal').modal('show');">Second</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="secondModal" >
    <div class="modal-body">
        Some error message goes here.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
$("#ModalId").appendTo("body");
```

For the detailed answer. Check this blog post

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/14/bootstrap-modal-dialog-showing-under-modal-background

Answer (score 0):

Just set the z-index of the first modal's container to 9999.

The default z-index for modals is 10000, which means the second modal will appear on top of the first. The default z-index of the fade overlay is also 9999, so as the second modal is rendered after the first, the overlay will render over the first modal.